# Dynamic page update by AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've got a problem.

I'm using AJAX to load pages and it works correctly, but I can't escape a bug.
When I load page, first time it works correctly but then I go to another page, AJAX loads the page I want, but it has double tags like `<head>` and `<footer>`.

I mean when I load page a second time, the page loads the same page in `<div>`.
It's like picture in picture.

I use in templates code like this:

```
<?php echo $header ?>
            My content
<?php echo $footer ?>
```

And every page load the same code after I get back to previous page by link.

My ajax code:

```
function showContent(link) {

    var cont = document.getElementById('content');
    var loading = document.getElementById('loading');
    window.history.replaceState('', 'Title', link);
    cont.innerHTML = loading.innerHTML;

    var http = createRequestObject();                   // создаем ajax-объект
    if( http ) {
        http.open('get', link);                         // инициируем загрузку страницы
        http.onreadystatechange = function () {         // назначаем асинхронный обработчик события
            if(http.readyState == 4) {

                cont.innerHTML = http.responseText;     // присваиваем содержимое
            }
        }
        http.send(null);    
    } else {
        document.location = link;   // если ajax-объект не удается создать, просто перенаправляем на адрес
    }
}

// создание ajax объекта
function createRequestObject() {
    try { return new XMLHttpRequest() }
    catch(e) {
        try { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP') }
        catch(e) {
            try { return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') }
            catch(e) { return null; }
        }
    }
}
```

What Can I do?
Because if I delete Tags header and footer my page doesn't have design at all.
And as u see, I change URL (important for me).

I need solution which will help me load templates without double-tagging.

Comment: What does `console.log(http.responseText)` on the second click show? This  will tell you if the problem in on your server script that provides the page content.

Answer (score 0):

In your template, be sure that you have something like

```
<?php echo $header ?>
        <div id="content">My content</div>
<?php echo $footer ?>
```

And that `id="content"` is unique, only there and not in your $header or $footer.

Answer (score 0):

If the pages you're pulling in with the JavaScript XHR (Ajax) also contain the PHP header and footer code, then you'll need to replace those also with your XHR:

```
<div id="content">
<?php echo $header ?>
My content
<?php echo $footer ?>
</div>
```

Wrap your content `div` tag around the header and footer in order to overwrite them rather than duplicate them.

---

Alternatively, the way I've implemented a PHP template system is like this:

*index.php*

```
<?php

// GET PAGE
if ( isset($_GET['page'])
  && '' != $_GET['page']
  && !preg_match('!^(/|\.|(ht|f)tp://)!', $_GET['page'])
) $page = $_GET['page'];
else $page = 'home.html';

// EXECUTE TEMPLATE
require('template.php');

?>
```

*template.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- plain HTML header goes here -->

<!-- RETRIEVE PAGE -->
<?php require('pages/' . $page); ?>

<!-- plain HTML footer goes here -->
</body>
</html>
```

*samplepage.html*

```
<h2>Sample Page Header</h2>
<p>Sample page content goes here.</p>
```

*phppage.php*

```
<h2>PHP Page Header</h2>
<p><?php echo 'PHP page content goes here.'; ?></p>
```

Everything goes to the *index.php* file. You can use PHP to block direct access to page files, or if using Apache web server you can use *.htaccess* to redirect all requests to the *index.php* file.

The technical URL looks like `http://example.net/index.php?page=samplepage.html`. But, using *.htaccess* can be effectively converted to `http://example.net/samplepage.html` with:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you are not clearing the previous content and the new content is being "`appended`" to the existing DOM.

So following points could be your solution.

1. In each `ajax` call, before updating the container element, clear the existing element, eg. `cont.innerHTML = '';`
2. Remember to keep track of any event bindings that are coming with the incoming response.
3. Move this line `var cont = document.getElementById('content');` inside the ajax call.